# Asking patches with coordinates contained in a list

Tags: netlogo

I have turtles with a memory that stores the coordinates of patches they travel:

```
turtles-own [
  memory
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [
    set memory (list)
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    move-to patch-ahead 1
    set memory (lput patch-here memory)
  ]
end
```

From this list, I want to ask something to any patches that have these coordinates and are white. I was trying:

```
ask patches at-points memory with [pcolor = white] [do-something]
```

But getting the error

```
Invalid list of points [(patch 0 1)]
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Fix it with:

```
set memory (lput ([list pxcor pycor] of patch-here) memory)
```

Comment: This may not always work as expected since `AT-POINTS` is relative to the turtle. If the turtle moves, then the frame of reference of `AT-POINTS` moves with it. You're far better off storing the patch itself, not just the coordinates. This way you can use `PATCH-SET` to convert the list to an agentset, like: `ASK (PATCH-SET MEMORY) WITH [ PCOLOR = WHITE ] [ DO-SOMETHING ]`

Answer (score 1):

Your answer works so feel free to ignore this. I just thought I'd offer you a few more options.

The problem with your original code is that you are not storing coordinates in a list but rather are storing patches in a list.
To work with agents that you have stored in a list, you will need to use `foreach`. This allows you to cycle through all agents in the list and ask them indidivually to change their color.

```
to change-pcolor-list
  
  ask turtles [
    foreach memory [
       the-patch -> ask the-patch [set pcolor white]
    ]
  ]
  
end
```

Another option is to store all the patches a turtle passes through in a turtles-own agent-set. This allows the turtles to call upon all the patches simultaneously instead of patch by patch and allows you to bypass the need for using anonymous procedures (which is what `foreach` uses).

```
turtles-own [
  memory-2
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [
    set memory-2 (patch-set)
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    move-to patch-ahead 1
    set memory-2 (patch-set memory-2 patch-here)
  ]
end

to change-pcolor-agentset
  
  ask turtles [
    ask memory-2 [
      set pcolor white
    ]
  ]

end
```